# I don't see the 'Ask Question' button on the site

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, design, asking-questions

I can add comments and add answers I believe.

I don't see anything on my account that says anything about my account being suspended. I refreshed a few times on my Google Chrome.

I see the 'Ask Question' button for other sites though.

[image]

Comment: Try looking to the left where the side menu is. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357281/announcing-a-design-experiment-re-placement-of-ask-question-button

Comment: I wonder, have manually cut this picture or do you use custom styles which hide the left sidebar and alters your header?

Comment: @Tom He has the left nav hidden by default, which is an option under site preferences.

Comment: @Tom nothing. I just added a full width screenshot

Comment: @CertainPerformance Possible, but the picture still was cut on the left side.

Comment: @Sho the button was visible for the meta site. Hidden for SO itself

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is part of [an experiment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357281/announcing-a-design-experiment-re-placement-of-ask-question-button) which was posted on Meta SE (but not on Meta SO as far as I can tell).

> Because the current location of the “Ask question” button is inconsistent, we want to move it. But first, we’re testing the proposed new location to ensure we don’t negatively impact question asking.

> We think **putting the ask a question button in the left nav** will be a more consistent spot for it. We also prefer the hierarchy of page layout in that position. But of course, we want to test it to make sure we’re not negatively impacting the question asking experience.

It is now located here:

[image: Question page after]

You'll need to open the left nav menu.

Comment: Wow, that is an absolutely terrible idea. The "how do I log out" questions are bad enough, why would they do the same thing to arguably the most important button on the site?

Comment: well, i mean, if people can't figure out how to ask questions, we wouldn't have to worry about the how do I ask questions questions.